# OpenGl texture questions

Tags: c#, opengl, textures

**Texturing headache...**

I can't understand where i go wrong here. My problem is that the texture is not aligned. The image on the left is the OpenGl textured quad, and the right is the original. Notice how the columns are offset in the textured quad.

[image: Mis-aligned texture]

I don't know if i am not loading the texture properly, or make a mistake during uploading it to videomemory, or simply use the wrong texCoords...

The image is a bmp (R8 G8 B8 A8) and the mistake lies somewhere in here:

(Loading of bitmap and uploading of texture)

```
        Bitmap fontBmp = new Bitmap("font2.bmp");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        fontBmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        int imageWidth = fontBmp.Width;
        int imageHeight = fontBmp.Height;
        byte[] fontBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
        fontBmp.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, (int)TexId.font);
        Gl.glPixelStorei(Gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_NEAREST);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_NEAREST);
        Gl.glTexEnvf(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, Gl.GL_MODULATE); // Try GL_DECAL...
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, fontBytes);
```

(The quad...)

```
        Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f + (0.5f / 128f), (127f / 128f) + (0.5f / 128f));
        Gl.glVertex2i(50, 50);

        Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f + (0.5f / 128f), 0f + (0.5f / 128f)); 
        Gl.glVertex2i(50, this.Height - 50);

        Gl.glTexCoord2f((127f / 128f) + (0.5f / 128f), 0f + (0.5f / 128f)); 
        Gl.glVertex2i(this.Width - 50, this.Height - 50);

        Gl.glTexCoord2f((127f / 128f) + (0.5f / 128f), (127f / 128f) + (0.5f / 128f)); 
        Gl.glVertex2i(this.Width - 50, 50);
```

Does anyone spot anything causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is NOT your texture coordinates.

The problem is that you're loading the texture wrong.  You're forgetting to remove the bitmap header, so all the real data is shifted over, and the end of each line is shifted onto the beginning of the next line.

Texture wrapping would wrap pixels from the right back onto the same line, but the out-of-place region is shifted down one row.  Texture wrapping also wouldn't occur with the "clamp to edge" mode you've enabled.

Comment: Ah! Duh! Makes total sense! From the top of your head, how do i get the bmp into the byte array without the header?

Comment: @mickey: I usually load the image using GDI+ and then [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx), this gives support for many compressed formats.  Then `BitmapData.Scan0` in the return value is the pointer which `glTexImage2D` needs.  Or else I use the binary PBM/PGM formats which have an extremely simple header and then data in the format expected by OpenGL.  In general, BMP files can be compressed and not directly usable by OpenGL.

Comment: I'll go with the lockbits method for now. Thanks for catching the bug, and the tips, Ben!

Comment: One question though. Where in the picture is the header? Shouldn't it be visible as garbage?

Comment: @mickey: You might be cutting off one row of the texture, I can't really tell.  To take care of pixel-perfect alignment, you'd probably want to adjust your quad coordinates by 1/2 pixel, not the texture coordinates.  Also, you're loading an alpha channel... the header might end up mostly transparent.

Comment: Wow, i feel like i have to keep asking you questions, because you just keep finding my errors ;)

Comment: Voigt Are you sure about offsetting vertex coords? I thought the purpose of the half pixel off was so that i sample the texture in the center of one pixel instead of in between four of them?

Comment: @mickey: You're welcome.  It's the mapping between pixels and texels that determines how the texture is sampled, so you can adjust the quad coordinates instead.  Usually, though, you just need to offset lines, not quads.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your glTexCoord coordinates. If you do

```
    Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    Gl.glVertex2i(50, 50);

    Gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f); 
    Gl.glVertex2i(50, this.Height - 50);

    Gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f); 
    Gl.glVertex2i(this.Width - 50, this.Height - 50);

    Gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f); 
    Gl.glVertex2i(this.Width - 50, 50);
```

,for instance, it should give you aligned positioning. Texture coordinates are from 0 to 1. If you changed the 1's to 2's in my example, your texture would repeat twice in each direction giving you four copies of it on that quad.

Note, this is untested code, I may have the wrong order of texture coordinates, but the point is that you should not use pixel dimensions but rather parameterize your texture dimensions to a [0,1] scale.

The reason is your texture parameters are set to wrap. Taking 0 to mean the beginning of the texture and 1 to mean 100% of its dimension, if you specify some non integer, then it will begin or end in the middle of your texture, whereas any nonzero integer is some multiple of the size of your texture and so it will appear to repeat.

EDIT:
This is also required to get the effect I'm talking about, to replace the setting you have for the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T.

```
    Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
    Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Gl.GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: Well, it looks the same with coordinates clamped to 0f and 1f. I add 0.5 pixel to sample the center center of a texel to avoid blurring. This is supposed to be correct... [link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/492068-pixel-perfect-opengl-without-glortho/), [link](http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/graphics/opengl-pixel-perfect.html)

Comment: I see. What is this.Height and this.Width? You could be applying the texture correctly to the wrong quad coordinates.

Comment: it is the width and height of the control i'm drawing to.